# Resolving 'RuntimeError: Size Mismatch in Tensor Dimension' in Signal Generation using Pre-trained RoBERTa

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to learn the obtained signal with pre-trained RoBERTa and generate the signal, but I get a RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (768) must match the size of tensor b (374125) at non-singleton dimension 1 error. What can I do to improve it?

```
import torch
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer, RobertaModel
from torch.nn import Linear
from torch.optim import Adam

# Load RoBERTa tokenizer and model
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
model = RobertaModel.from_pretrained('roberta-base')

# Add a linear layer on top of RoBERTa to generate signal
signal_size = 2993 * 125
model.classifier = Linear(model.config.hidden_size, 374125)
# Prepare your signal data as input sequences and target signals
input_sequences = [tokenizer.encode("signal {}".format(i), return_tensors='pt') for i in range(16)]
target_signals = [train_all_data.transpose(1,3,0,2).reshape(16, signal_size)[i] for i in range(16)]
target_signals = [torch.tensor(signal) for signal in target_signals]

# Define loss function and optimizer
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Train the model on your signal data
for epoch in range(1000):
    for input_ids, target in zip(input_sequences, target_signals):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(input_ids)[0].mean(dim=1)
        loss = criterion(outputs, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
# Use the fine-tuned model to generate a new signal
input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Generate a new signal", return_tensors='pt')).unsqueeze(0)
outputs = model(input_ids)[0].mean(dim=1)
new_signal = outputs.detach().numpy()
```

Comment: Include full error stacktrace and print shapes of various tensors. Moreover the code for the Roberta model may be needed if the error occurs within the `model.__call__()`

Comment: Despite my best efforts to comprehend the necessary modifications, I remain perplexed regarding the appropriate procedure to make changes to the code.

Comment: Yes, you need to include the above information in your question if you want users to be able to help you